# Laravel 5 and EAV relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, entity-attribute-value

I'm in trouble with eav model. Basically; i have three tables. User, UserInfo, Country.

```
User                userinfo               Country
---------           ------------           ------------
id                  id                     id
username            user_id                country_name
pass                option_id
etc                 option_value
```

I connected user and userinfo models succesfully. There is a no problem.
I retrieving user infos in user model with this:

```
$this->info->where('option_id', $key)->first()->option_value;
```

My problem is right there. I'am storing "country_id" in option_id and option_value.

In example:

```
userinfo
--------
id                  1
user_id             5
option_id           country_id
option_value        3
```

I am running this query from user model

```
$this->info->where('option_id', 'country_id')->first()->option_value;
```

It returns 3. There is a no problem. My problem is i couldn't get country_name.
I don't know which relationship to use for this.
I can make this using "DB" class but then i need use another queries for all of theese types. It's not the best solution.

Can someone help me?

Edit : I am looking for like this solution (if it's possible):

```
$this->info->where('option_id', $key)->first()->option_value->country_name;
```

Edit : I am using laravel 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Country model belongs to the userinfo.
On your userinfo model, you should define the relationship.

UserInfo Class

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Country', 'local_key', 'parent_key');
}
```

In this case, your `'local_key'` would be `'option_id'` and your `'parent_key'` would be `'id'`.

Once you've defined the relationship, you can get all attribute of country like this:

```
$this->info->where('option_id', $key)->first()->country()->get();
```

Comment: I am edited     return $this->belongsTo('App\Country', 'country_id', 'id');  to     return $this->belongsTo('App\Country', 'option_value', 'id'); Its worked to me, thx a lot :)